# Java rgb troubles

Tags: java, colors, discord, bots

I am trying to use RGB to set a color for a embed on a discord bot I'm working on (yes in java) and am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to set the color to `#EABE23` or `234, 190, 35`. I've tried friends and reading through documentation but haven't found anything, anyone know which way to point?

Code:

```
if (event.getMessageContent().equalsIgnoreCase(prefix + "author")) {
    EmbedBuilder author = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(BotName)
            .setDescription("Created by: " + Creator)
            .setAuthor("All code written and owned by: " + Creator, "https://github.com/me", "")
            .setColor(Color.yellow);
    event.getChannel().sendMessage(author);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code so far where we can see how you are trying to set the color? That would make it easier to help.

Comment: edited it so that you can see the code.

Comment: java.awt.Color class has a Color(float r, float g, float b) constructor, and a static Color decode(String str). Why can't you use one of these?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try button color picker on below link (Embed visualizer), it will calculate expected color value

https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/

eg #EABE23 -> "color": 15384099

Answer (score 0):

Hey there, you can just add 0x to your color.

Example: `#EABE23` to `0xEABE23`, code would be like that: `.setColor(0xEABE23)`